# angular url with path variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to change angular url to /jobs/id. i wrote like below one. will this work?

$location.path("/JobHire/jobs/"+response.data.id);

how should i write route config? i configured like this

```
$routeProvider
            .when('/jobs/:id',{
                templateUrl:'partials/job.html'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo:'/'
            }); 

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Is this a correct way. How to retrieve those parameters inside a controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use current url params in angular controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449743/how-to-use-current-url-params-in-angular-controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a controller.

```
$routeProvider
            .when('/jobs/:id',{
                templateUrl:'partials/job.html',
                controller: 'jobController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo:'/'
            });
```

and inside the controller you need to do something like:

```
.controller(function($scope, $http, $location) {

    var my_id = $location.id;

    $http.get('some_API/jobs/' + my_id).success(function(data) {
      //do something width data;
    });

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to define a controller in your route config as

```
$routeProvider
            .when('/jobs/:id',{
                templateUrl:'partials/job.html',
                controller: 'somecontroller'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo:'/'
            }); 

app.controller([$scope,$routeParams], function($scope, $routeParams){
 var id = $routeParams.id;
});
```

This is how you can get the id from url.